# How do I override a widget method in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, widget

I need to override the renderPageButton() method in the Yii2 LinkPager widget.  The method documentation specifically says "You may override this method to customize the generation of page buttons" but I can't figure out how to do that.  Thanks.

Comment: You have to create your own widget and extend it from LinkPager widget, then you can overwrite parents protected method to your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding [LinkPager](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-linkpager) can be done this way:

Create a new file `./widgets/MyLinkPager.php`:

```
<?php
namespace app\widgets;
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;
class MyLinkPager extends LinkPager 
{
    protected function renderPageButtons()
    {
        // do whatever you want, it may help to
        // copy code from parent::renderPageButtons() 
        // or even call 
        return parent::renderPageButtons();
    }
}
```

And then use it this way in your view (see here: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-pagination):

```
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;

echo LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $pagination,
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The class you want to override is documented [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-linkpager).

You can override it in the following way:

- Create a new directory in your yii2 app root folder, like widgets
- Create a new php file (like MyLinkPager.php) and a new class in it (MyLinkPager) which extens yii\widgets\LinkPager
- You can use "app\widgets" namespace (i.e. if you are working with the basic yii2 app)
- In your class, implement only the function you want to override from the original class
- Use your new class wherever you want instead of the original one